# Django TypedChoiceField choices insert values from the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Product model that has `stock = models.PositiveIntegerField ()` is the number of goods in stock. When creating a product, I create a random quantity of goods. The product is added to the basket and there I can change the number of goods. I would like to display the number I entered when creating.

**forms.py**

```
class CartProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=[**here need product.stock form this product**], coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

How can I pass an argument to this form so that product.stock is displayed in choices parameter?

**show_cart.html** This file shows us our shopping basket.

```
{% for item in cart %}
    {% with product=item.product %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>

            <td>
                <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' product.id %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                    <button>Обновить</button>
                </form>
            </td>

            <td><a href="{% url 'cart:cart_delete' product.id %}">Удалить</a></td>
            <td>{{ item.price }} руб.</td>
        </tr>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

It looks like you can see select forms are empty.[image]

Here is the method that gives us this page

```
def cart_show(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})

    return render(request, 'cart/cart_show.html', {'cart': cart})
```

How can I enter the values of the quantity of goods in stock in the TypedChoiceField field which I introduced?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  context processors, take a look at it:
https://labofcoding.com/how-write-and-use-custom-template-processors-django/